# Subscript import to MAS200

Tags: sage

We are planning an import into mass too. One of our fields has "chemical name." These chemical names have subscript. Example: H<sub>2</sub>0, where the 2 is small... Can this be done, or does it have to be all in regular script?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://serverfault.com/questions/247377/subscript-import-to-mas200). If you need to have a question moved, you can click the `flag` link and ask a moderator.

Answer (score 0):

If MAS 200 supports Unicode character sets, you can use Unicode Character 'SUBSCRIPT TWO' (U+2082)